# Invalid or corrupted PDF file when php opens pentaho report

Tags: php, pdf, curl, report, pentaho

We have a PHP application to handle the company's orders.

On the development and production servers, we can view an order in the firefox built-in PDF viewer before printing it. The order template is made with Pentaho Report Designer and filled with dynamic data.

I want to view an order with my computer's local data (copy of the production DB) but it just opens a blank pdf tab.

I'm guessing I need to install either Pentaho BI-Server or Pentaho Data Integration on my computer, but I can't seem to understand which one.

---

**Edit**

I forgot to say that everything works already for the development and production branches. Pentaho Data Integration is installed on the server where the svn repositories are (for both development and production), and Pentaho BI-Server is installed only on the development deployment server (so should not work if the blank tab was because BI-server was not installed).

I figured my local data source was wrong in the Pentaho Report Designer.

I get these warnings and errors with firebug when the blank pdf tab opens.

> Warning: The linearization data is not available or unreadable pdf data is found
>
> Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
>
> Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
> PDF.JS Build: e22ee54
> Message: InvalidPDFException

And somewhere in the code, curl_exec fails

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
$result = curl_exec($this->ch);
```

Comment: On Chrome, it says "Failed to load PDF document"

Answer (score 1):

I can solve your doubt,
BI- Server you can visualize your reports into report viewer,
Data Integration is for converting data from for Example Excel to Any database and you can create Transformation and Jobs into it..

so if you don't want to perform any of the operations explicitly or don't want to create any batch process then Data-integration in of no use..

Download and extract BI-Server rest you will automatically understand.